# SCons: how to debug what action does?

Tags: python, scons

I'm trying to understand why `Sphinx` builder for SCons doesn't work.  The essential part of the code that I want to debug boils down to this:

```
SCons.Action.Action('$SPHINXCOM', '$SPHINXCOMSTR')
```

I know that in theory, `$SPHINXCOM` should expand to `$SPHINXBUILD $_SPHINXOPTIONS ${SOURCE.attributes.root} ${TARGET.attributes.root}`, but since SCons never seems to run this action, I can never trace what was it thinking it should run.

Trying to navigate SCons' own code is a road to hell... it's completely opaque, with dozens of delegations and guesswork and so on... After hours of trying, I still cannot find the code that is supposed to run when this action is evaluated, or whatever the correct term is... but at some point the methods of the action start returning empty string, at which point it seems to stop.

By reading through the `--help` options, I cannot see anything that would increase verbosity or print any more diagnostic messages than what is already printed (there isn't really any logging in the code anyway, so there seems to be nothing to print anyway).  I would be happy to find the code that executes the action, so that I would know at which point the action does have to have to produce any non-null values in its methods...  I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to that code.

---

Just to give you a taste of what is going on with this `Action` thing.  My findings so far are as follows:

1. `Action` calls two helper methods conditioned on the type of arguments, which in my case seems to delegate the work to `ActionBase` class.
2. `ActionBase`, after inspecting the types of arguments (all of which are passed through `**kw`, i.e. anonymously) seems to then delegate the work to `ActionAction` class.
3. `ActionAction` class then inspects the arguments, which have now been altered by the previous inspections, and calls `CommandAction` class to deal with the input.
4. `CommandAction` now again delegates to `Action`.
5. `Action` now received the same basic info in the arguments, but it's formatted differently: instead of the second argument being a string, it is a dict with a single key in it.
6. `Action` now delegates to `_Action`...

Somewhere around that point the methods of "action" object start returning empty string where a I'd expect to see the generated command.  Given the overall structure and smell of the code, I think I only scratched the surface of this devious delegation scheme, but I don't have enough of inside knowledge to cut through all of it to the place, where "action" methods are really accessed.  If I knew where that happens, I'd be able to find a way to structure the arguments to `Action` in such a way that they make it in one piece to that place.

Comment: Have you checked the [MAN page of SCons](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) for the correct usage of the various "tree" options that are available? You will want to ensure that the Action really fires, i.e. that *SCons* sees that your target is not up-to-date. Can you provide a MWE, demonstrating how you try to run the Action in question?

Comment: None of the `--tree` options are useful. Also, I already mentioned that I've read this info... I'm not sure what do you want to see in the example? I don't know what to write there because I don't know what code I'm looking for. All I know is what that code is supposed to do, but that's about it.

Comment: Where is the target of the sphinx action with relation to where you are running SCons? Is it in a subdirectory of the current directory? Or is it in a different directory tree?

Comment: In your first sentence you claim that the Sphinx Builder doesn't work. Please show us the SConstruct you tried, leading to your conclusion. If possible, add which version of SCons you have tried, under which OS, how you called *SCons* (if any arguments were given) and what the output of the command was (verbatim copy of the displayed output).

Comment: @bdbaddog it is in the same directory tree as the SConstruct file, but this is not important. I know that the action is being called, because its methods are accessed, my problem is in finding what that string translates to when it is called.

Comment: @dirkbaechle sorry, you don't understand the question. I don't need you to help me to make SCons work, as in running a specific build. I can do that myself by rewriting a build not using third-party Sphinx plugin but writing mine instead. I'm asking, in a specific scenario when the third-party plugin used `Action()`, how would I find out what that will translate to, given first argument to `Action()` was a template string.

Comment: Did you try: --debug=presub ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that *SCons* runs in two phases: a "parse" phase, and a "build" phase. The call trace that you describe above is from the "parse" phase. This is where the SConstructs get read and digested. In this phase, *SCons* simply keeps track of which source and target nodes are required (get defined) by the different Builder calls like "`env.PDF("test.ltx")`". For a target node, like "`test.pdf`" in this example, it also registers the Environment to be used ("`env`" here). In `Builder::_execute` an instance of the class `Executor` gets registered with each target, keeping track of which Builder actions have to get triggered.

But it doesn't execute the required single Actions right away! This will only happen later, in the "build" phase, when *SCons* detects that the target "`test.pdf`" is indeed not up-to-date.

Then, `Task::execute` (in Taskmaster.py) gets called, which invokes the `Node::build()` method of the target node. There the registered Executor gets called and expands the Actions in `Executor::execute_action_list()`.

*Remark*: Take into account that the string `'$SPHINXCOM'` gets substituted with the variables as being set for the current Environment. So, you don't have to manipulate the arguments given to the `Action` constructor, but the variables in the used Environment for getting the output you need.

I hope this helps you further. `;)`

Comment: Yes, by the time it gets to `Executor.execute_action_list()` the "action" object's methods that render it to string produce garbage (empty string). It will take time though to understand what happened in between and how the original arguments got lost... I'll update once I find those.

Comment: I'd probably dump the contents of the Environment in "```Action::process```" next, and then start to add some "print" debugging to "```Subst::scons_subst```"...just as an idea.